# Why Ropsten etherscan and local Ropsten are not showing the same data?

Tags: testnets, ropsten

I am running geth to sync to ropsten testnet. I verified that block 0 are identical. However, seems like the local geth doesnt sync as high as the ropsten.etherscan.io site claims and checking individual blocks showing different transaction. I am a bit confused on what is going on here. Any insights would be appreciated.
Chris

Comment: Basically what I am trying to do is test out a contract on the testnet as described here blog.zeppelin.solutions/…. I was using faucet.ropsten.be:3001 to add ether to my account, but when I sync locally using geth --testnet --rpc console, the funds dont show. However, on ropsten.etherscan.io they do. So it seems to be I am not syncing to the right testnet?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to clarify your topic as to whether or not you are talking about the ropsten testnet and just that, or the ropsten testnet and a local testnet that only exists on your node. I'll touch on both though

1) Geth node doesn't match block count on https://ropsten.etherscan.io

Give your node time to download the entire blockchain, ropsten has millions of blocks to download, and even more millions of state entries to download. To watch your progress when attached to a geth console you can use the **eth.Syncing** command.

2) roptsen testnet and local testnet not the same

Block 0 is the genesis block, and is the only block generated by a human, and sets the initial settings for the blockchain. You can use the same genesis file in different networks, but it doesn't mean that the two networks will be the same. For both your local testnet and the ropsten testnet to match you would basically have to redo every single transaction from ropsten, to your local testnet.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Basically what I am trying to do is test out a contract on the testnet as described here https://blog.zeppelin.solutions/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-smart-contracts-in-ethereum-848f08001f05. I was using http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001/ to add ether to my account, but when I sync locally using geth --testnet --rpc console, the funds dont show. However, on https://ropsten.etherscan.io/ they do. So it seems to be I am not syncing to the right testnet?

Comment: How long are you waiting to check on the console? Your balance won't display until you have *fully* synced the blockchain.

Comment: Days; synching status is false, but the highest block number is smaller than what's shown on ropsten.etherscan.io. also, checking specific block number transaction records seem to differ from the local to the web site...

Comment: Once you've reached a certain block height, your node will start downloading state entries of which there are upwards of 30 million. Depending on your network connection, disk type, number of peers, computer strength, etc... it can drastically effect your sync time. Why are you using ropsten? It has a history of being abused and spammed, and quite slow. Rinkeby is a much faster blockchain, that will sync way faster than ropsten.